# Add ability to open selected question in a new browser tab using keyboard shortcuts

Tags: feature-request, navigation, keyboard-shortcuts

On the homepage or `/questions`, one can press <kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd>, or <kbd>K</kbd> to select a question, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the question. Unfortunately, however, there doesn't seem to be a way to open the question in a new tab.

- Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> opens the question in a new *window*.
- Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> does nothing.
- Pressing the <kbd>menu</kbd> key isn't helpful because the element doesn't actually have focus.

I don't know if giving the "selected" element the focus would have side effects. If it doesn't, it's not undesired by other users, and it doesn't break someone's [workflow](https://xkcd.com/1172/), then it could be a good solution. Otherwise, maybe have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> work in the same way that
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> does.

Comment: Those keys do nothing in my browser (firefox).

Comment: Standard keyboard navigation (`Tab`, `Ctrl+Enter`) works fine for me.

Comment: @DavidPostill You need to enable keyboard shortcuts from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current).

Comment: @OrangeDog Not sure if I understood you correctly. Obviously, when the element has focus (via `Tab` or otherwise), then `Ctrl+Enter` _will_ work. SE's [keyboard shortcuts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/keyboard-shortcuts/info), however, work differently

Comment: Oh, I always turn off custom shortcut systems. One day you'll start typing when you think you're in a text box, and all kinds of horrible stuff happens.